# Cannot connect express js with firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
const FCM = require("fcm-node")
const senderId = require('./fcm/uzhavarmann-46381-firebase-adminsdk-k7nn5-a324f0c4ce.json');

const fcm = new FCM(senderId);
```

Sending Notification :

```
    app.post('/send-fcm', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const message = {
            to: 'fEoFXrGRS-GFYUBJlI3ddR:APA91bGJXzyyfMEjwmuZvWFzFvkpkmlWf-2S_JKqaU9ft2kpBoFD0tisVyTuy3JMZBLzbnV3IH2IHCnq-dB-03NiXs1ln1fbekxGpkRZaJMjvsxT5NONd-xUMFSaApZzvcUwWxBI6t6I',
            notification: {
              title: 'Notification Title',
              body: 'Notification Body',
            },
          };
          
          fcm.send(message, function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error sending message:', err);
            } else {
              console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            }
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error sending message' });
      }
  });
```

i got error like

Error sending message: FirebaseError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: invalid_grant (Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.)". There are two likely causes: (1) your server time is not properly synced or (2) your certificate key file has been revoked. To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project. If not, generate a new key file at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk.
at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/mahatapes/Desktop/Uzhavarmann_Api/node_modules/fcm-node/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
at new FirebaseAppError (/Users/mahatapes/Desktop/Uzhavarmann_Api/node_modules/fcm-node/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:70:23)
at /Users/mahatapes/Desktop/Uzhavarmann_Api/node_modules/fcm-node/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:106:23
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errorInfo: {
code: 'app/invalid-credential',
message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: invalid_grant (Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.)". There are two likely causes: (1) your server time is not properly synced or (2) your certificate key file has been revoked. To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project. If not, generate a new key file at [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk.'](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk.%27)
}
}